# Subdividing array into lesser arrays into lesser arrays doesnt return correct result

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, memory-management

User provides 2 arguments, n-amount of float elements that will be stored in an array, w-amount of rows that contain parts of subdivided array. If n%w is equal to 0, distribute elements between arrays equaly, otherwise the last array contains +n%w elements more. My code always show proper amount of rows, but i don't know why for n%w=0 it always shows 4 elements in a row, which often ends up in printing 0.000000 in the end. For n%w=1 segmentation error occurs.Im writing my program in Linux, nano editor. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(char argc, char* argv[]) {

    //checking if user provided 2 arguments
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments !\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n, w;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &w);
    //creating an array that will contain float values that we will use later on   
    float* myarray = (float*)malloc(n);

    srand(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        myarray[i] = 1000. * rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    float** doublearray = (float**)malloc(w * sizeof(float*));
    int columns = n / w;
    int modulo = n % w;

    //if n%w equals zero, distribute values equaly between rows
    if (modulo == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            doublearray[i] = (float*)malloc(columns * sizeof(float));
        }
    }
    //if n%w does not equal zero, increase last row size by modulo
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < w - 1; i++) {
            doublearray[i] = (float*)malloc(columns * sizeof(float));
        }
        doublearray[w] = (float*)malloc((columns + modulo) * sizeof(float));
    }

    //distributing elements in 2 dimensional array
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(doublearray[i]); j++) {
            doublearray[i][j] = myarray[number];
            number++;
        }
    }

    //printing out the result
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(doublearray[i]); j++) {
            printf("%f", doublearray[i][j]);
            printf(" "); printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is result for arguments n=10,w=5

840.187744  394.382935  783.099243  798.440063

911.647339  197.551376  335.222748  768.229614

277.774719  553.969971  0.000000    0.000000

0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000

0.000000    0.000000    840.187744  0.000000

But it should be

840.187744  394.382935

783.099243  798.440063

911.647339  197.551376

335.222748  768.229614

277.774719  553.969971

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a simple example of input as well as actual and expected output.

Comment: `sizeof(doublearray[i])` will give you the number of _bytes_, not the number of elements! And since it is a pointer, the result is 4 (or 8). Just use `columns`.

Comment: There is no `doublearray[w]`. The last element is `doublearray[w-1]`.

Comment: `float* myarray = (float*)malloc(n);` -> `float* myarray = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));`, but there are possibly more errors

Comment: Is there any other way that i can get the lenght of an array, by the fact that in second case the lenght of the last row is different from the others ?

Comment: In this code you can't. I suggest you repeat the part when module is not zero, just as you did when allocating the arrays.

Comment: These subarrays will be passed to a function later on, and i need to get the length of the array, can i somehow count amount of the elements in a subarray? What would be a stop statement if i do it in in a loop ?

Comment: regarding: `int main(char argc, char* argv[]) {`   The first parameter to `main()` is `int`, not `char`  The posted code goes downhill from there.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 0):

For starters in this code snippet

```
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < w - 1; i++) {
        doublearray[i] = (float*)malloc(columns * sizeof(float));
    }
    doublearray[w] = (float*)malloc((columns + modulo) * sizeof(float));
}
```

there is used invalid index `w`. The valid range of indices for the array is `[0, w)`.

So you have to write

```
    doublearray[w-1] = (float*)malloc((columns + modulo) * sizeof(float));
```

This loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(doublearray[i]); j++) {
```

does not make sense. The type of the expression `doublearray[i]` is `float *`. So `sizeof( float * )` does not yield the number of allocated elements for the one-dimensional array.

I am sure there are several approaches to organize the loops. I can suggest the approach demonstrated in the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t M = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t N = 3;

    int **b = malloc( M / N * sizeof( int * ) );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M / N; i++ )
    {
        size_t n = M - ( i + 1 ) * N < N ? N + M % N : N;
        b[i] = malloc( n < sizeof( int ) );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M / N; i++ )
    {
        size_t n = M - ( i + 1 ) * N < N ? N + M % N : N;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) b[i][j] = a[N * i + j];
    }


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M / N; i++ )
    {
        size_t n = M - ( i + 1 ) * N < N ? N + M % N : N;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( "%d ", b[i][j] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M / N; i++ )
    {
        free( b[i] );
    }

    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9
```